# Behave gherkin python pyautogui

Tags: python, gherkin, pyautogui, python-behave

```
Scenario: Navigate from overview to system details
    Given the login page is displyed
    When log in is selected
    the user selects a red bubble
    Then bubble-details are displayed


@When('the user selects a red bubble')
def click_checkpoint(self):
    def find_checkpoint(self):
        p = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('venv/screens/2018-04-26_0806.png')
        c = pyautogui.center(p)
        d = list(c)
    find_checkpoint(pyautogui.click(d[0], d[1], duration=1))
```

**I keep getting an error on:**
  File "src\Playground\Navigation\steps\interaction.py", line 55, in click_checkpoint
    find_checkpoint(pyautogui.click(d[0], d[1], duration=1))
NameError: name 'd' is not defined

obviously i have not structured the python correctly but lack the skills to trouble shoot it, maybe someone has a quick fix.

The goal is to define the pyautogui and run it immediately after but in the same step

Answer (score 0):

It is because `d` is defined in the score within the inner function `find_checkpoint`

When you define a function, all the variables in them becomes local. If you REALLY need the variables to be global, you can use the `global` keyword.

[See this question about scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

What I believe you really need to do is return the value of `d` and then assign it;

```
@When('the user selects a red bubble')
def click_checkpoint(self):
    def find_checkpoint(self):
        p = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('venv/screens/2018-04-26_0806.png')
        c = pyautogui.center(p)
        return list(c)
    d = find_checkpoint(self)
    find_checkpoint(pyautogui.click(d[0], d[1], duration=1))
```

Comment: thats because i can't call the find checkpoint unless it is outside the inner function. i need to call the coordinates in the same step somehow

Comment: thanks, the error has now changed to:

pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 407, in center
    return (coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

(which is closer to reality)

Comment: You could add a print after assigning `d` to see what its contents are.

Comment: `def click_checkpoint(context):
    p = context.browser(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("venv/screens/2018-04-26_0806.png"))
    c = pyautogui.center(p)
    d = list(c)
    pyautogui.click(d[0], d[1], duration=1)`

The problem is that as soon as i put it into a function it doesn't find the coordinates. i'ts like it is trapped inside the function and can't look outside. so i tried calling the context which has the browser session stored but im notgood enough to combine it